# Using `async` without really needing it

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Is it useful to declare a function with the `async` keyword even when `await` is not used inside the function?

Example:

```
async function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (...)
  });
}
```

A collegue of mine uses to declare **all** its asynchronous functions like that for the only reason that it allows to quicky know when the function is asynchronous or not.

But I'm not really convinced. What do you think? Is it a good practice?

Comment: This is a *highly* opinionated topic. I don't think you could get a useful on-topic answer.

Comment: One thing people forget what `async` does,.. It guarantees the return will be a promise.  In your example it's pretty much guaranteed.  But let's say the `return new Promise` was conditional, and maybe you returned `false` on the other condition, using `async` here would guarantee that the `false` is returned as a `promise`, otherwise it would be just `false`.   From the caller end using `await`, it wouldn't have any effect as `await` on a none promise is fine too.  But if someone was using the `then` callback it would fail.

Comment: It is not opinionated, there is a reason to do this - it changes the stack frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this bad practice. The purpose of the `async` keyword is to allow the use of `await`. Per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously
>   via the event loop, using an **implicit** Promise to return its
>   result. **But the syntax and structure of your code using async
>   functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.**

The syntax and structure of your colleague's code is clearly not like "using standard synchronous functions".

Anytime I find something unexpected / not idiomatic in code like this, I have to spend more time understanding the code and it takes away from productivity. Can I remove the `async` keyword and will the code still work? This is going to take some effort to figure out and be 100% sure.